# Powershell search for file, if found, open it

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to search for a file, if the file is found i need to open it.

This code works and as an output i get the full file name. Now i need to open that specific file.

```
[void] System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic')
        
$firstFileName = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Enter First file name (33xxxx)", "First file name")
        
        
Get-ChildItem -Path K:\ -Filter "$firstFileName*.xlsm" -Recurse ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force
    
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.visible = $true
$Workbook = $Excel.workbooks.open($RG)
```

Comment: How can i get the path of the file found in a variable?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
$KDpath = "K:\"

[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic')

$RGFileName = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("RG-Nummer eingeben (33xxxx)", "RG-Nummer")

$RG = Get-ChildItem -Path "$KDpath" -Filter "$RGFileName*.xlsm" -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName

$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.visible = $true
$Workbook = $Excel.workbooks.open($RG)
```

Answer (score -1):

Per your comment. Assuming you're returning multiple paths with that name, you can loop through them opening them up using the *Excel COM Object*.

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic')
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application 
$Excel.visible = $true 

$firstFileName = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Enter First file name (33xxxx)", "First file name")
$GCISplat = @{
    Path    = "K:\"
    Filter  = "$firstFileName*.xlsm"
    Recurse = $true
    Force   = $true
    ErrorACtion = 'SilentlyContinue'
}

$FilesFound = (Get-ChildItem @GCISplat).FullName
    foreach ($RG in $FilesFound) {

        $Workbook = $Excel.workbooks.open($RG)

    }
```

If only one file path is returned each time, the loop is unnecessary, so removing the `foreach` loop, and assigning the path to `$RG` instead should work.

```
$RG = (Get-ChildItem @GCISplat).FullName
```

Comment: Doesn't open the file

Comment: I added this to my code, but the question is, how can i get the path of the file found and / or how can i make it open the file found. How can i put the files path and name in a variable like "$RG"?

`$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.visible = $true
$Workbook = $Excel.workbooks.open($RG)`